# Aggregating data and getting sum and counts

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have an object in python with a lot of rows:

**INPUT :**

```
    Team1     Player1     idTrip13     133
    Team2     Player333   idTrip10     18373
    Team3     Player22    idTrip12     17338899
    Team2     Player293   idTrip02     17656
    Team3     Player20    idTrip11     1883
    Team1     Player1     idTrip19     19393
```

and I need to aggregate this data (like a pivot table).

**OUTPUT I am working on:**

```
Team1   Player1 : 2 trips : sum(133+19393)
Team2   Player333 : 1 trip : 18373; Player293 : 1 trip : 17656
Team3   Player22 : 1 trip : 17338899; Player20 : 1 trip : 1883
```

Could someone suggest the appropriate object in Python to use such that I could have the following output?

```
print team, player, trips, time
```

Comment: Are you using `pandas` for that?

Comment: nope, I don't know that

Comment: As suggested, look into the pandas package, put the data in a DataFrame, it can do pivot tables, or just use the groupby function. http://pandas.pydata.org

Comment: Are `team`, `player`, `trips`, `time` lists or can you put them in lists?

Comment: I can put them in lists

Comment: Can you install packages, specifically can you do `pip install pandas`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use groupby function for [pandas DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe)**

1. Put your data into a list of lists, each inner list will be a row in the dataframe.

   ```
   In[1]:

   mydata = [['Team1', 'Player1', 'idTrip13', 133], ['Team2', 'Player333', 'idTrip10', 18373],
   ['Team3', 'Player22', 'idTrip12', 17338899], ['Team2', 'Player293','idTrip02', 17656], 
   ['Team3', 'Player20', 'idTrip11', 1883], ['Team1', 'Player1', 'idTrip19', 19393]]

   df = pd.DataFrame(mydata, columns = ['team', 'player', 'trips', 'time'])

   df
   Out[1]:
        team    player       trips      time
   0   Team1   Player1     idTrip13    133
   1   Team2   Player333   idTrip10    18373
   2   Team3   Player22    idTrip12    17338899
   3   Team2   Player293   idTrip02    17656
   4   Team3   Player20    idTrip11    1883
   5   Team1   Player1     idTrip19    19393
   ```
2. [Call `groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups), pass the column you wish to use as your grouper,
   and apply a function to the groups.

---

Examples

**Ex. 1** Find the number of trips each team went on. `team` is the grouper, and we apply the function `count()` on column `['trips']`.

```
In[2]:
trip_count = df.groupby(by = ['team'])['trips'].count() 

trip_count              
Out[2]:          

 team
Team1    2
Team2    2
Team3    2
Name: trips, dtype: int64
```

**Ex. 2 (multiple columns)**: Find the total time each player on a team spent traveling. We use 2 columns `['team', 'player']` as the grouper, and apply the function `sum()` on column `['time']`.

```
In[3]:              
trip_time = df.groupby(by = ['team', 'player'])['time'].sum() 

trip_time        
Out[3]:

 team   player   
Team1  Player1         19526
Team2  Player293       17656
       Player333       18373
Team3  Player20         1883
       Player22     17338899
Name: time, dtype: int64
```

**Ex. 3 [(multiple functions)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once):** For each player on a team, find the total number of trips and total time spent traveling.

```
player_total = df.groupby(by = ['team', 'player']).agg({'time' : 'sum', 'trips' : 'count'})

player_total
Out[4]:
                 trips  time
team    player      
Team1   Player1     2   19526
Team2   Player293   1   17656
        Player333   1   18373
Team3   Player20    1   1883
        Player22    1   17338899
```

Comment: Hi thanks it works. But I need to have, for instance Team2; Player293   1   17656; Player333   1   18373 in the same line (and not 2 lines). Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @John Doe  Happy to help, and welcome to StackOverflow! Since the question was marked as too broad and my answer was becoming long, I thought it may be better to split the answer into 2. To see how to print everything in one line, please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539891/printing-all-rows-in-each-level-of-multiindex-pd-dataframe-in-one-row/34539978#34539978). I used this answer to show how to use pandas to get the sum and counts. If you can, try to edit your post accordingly.
If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.